# File encoding Data Extract - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, encoding

we exported few files (.CSV, .ZIP) from Marketing Cloud into SFTP folder using Data Extract and File Transfer as activities.
We noticed that files' encoding is 'UCS-2 LE BOM' and not 'UTF-8' as expected.
Where can i change file encoding in Marketing Cloud Account?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can ask to the support (via ticket) to enable the tar.gz compression.
Note: it will change the date formatting of the extracted data too though.

Answer (score 0):

Default encoding is "UCS-2 LE BOM" when you use "Data Extract" with "Data Extension Extract" for "Extract type".

To convert to "UTF-8", you have to create a new "Data Extract" with "Extract Type" = "Convert", and choose "UTF-8" on the next step and put this activity between your 1st "Data Extract" activity and the "File Transfer" activity

Another solution is to use the "Extract Type" = "Data Extension Extract with File Encoding BOM and gzip", in which you have the choice of the encoding this time but it will result in a ".tar.gz" file and not ".zip", but if you can manage "tar.gz" file, go ahead !